# Custom post category query

Tags: php, wordpress

I register a custom post & taxonomy in function.php . But the problem when i query the custom post in a template no category show. I want such as (Posted In :Uncategorized).My custom post register,taxonomy & Custom post query code given.

```
    // register Custom Post Types
function create_post_types() {
    register_post_type(
        'portfolio', 
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Portfolio'),
                'singular_name' => __('Portfolio'),
                'add_new' => 'Add New Portfolio',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Portfolio',
                'capability_type' => 'post',
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'rewrite' => true,
                'query_var' => true
            ),
            'menu_position' => 6,
            'public' => true,
            'supports' => array(
                'title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments','page-attributes'
            ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio', 'with_front' => false ),
            'taxonomy' => array('category', 'post_tag')
        )
    );    
}
add_action('init', 'create_post_types');


// register Taxonomies
function create_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'portfolio-category',
        'portfolio', 
        array (
        'hierarchical' => true, 
        'label' => __('Portfolio Categories'),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug'=> 'portfolio', 
            'with_front'    => false 
            )
        )
    );    
}
add_action('init', 'create_taxonomies');
```

Comment: My Query Post..<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type'=> 'portfolio');
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
<div >
 <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
 <?php the_content(); ?> <br /><br />
 Posted In :<?php the_category(', '); ?>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>

Answer (score 0):

I testes your code and the issue is quite simple. You have a typo in your arguments array. To connect the custom post type to categories and tags you have to use `taxonomies` and not `taxonomy` as the array key. So you code should looke like this:

```
// register Custom Post Types
function create_post_types() {
    register_post_type(
        'portfolio', 
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Portfolio'),
                'singular_name' => __('Portfolio'),
                'add_new' => 'Add New Portfolio',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Portfolio',
                'capability_type' => 'post',
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'rewrite' => true,
                'query_var' => true
            ),
            'menu_position' => 6,
            'public' => true,
            'supports' => array(
                'title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments','page-attributes'
            ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio', 'with_front' => false ),
            'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag')
        )
    );    
}
add_action('init', 'create_post_types');
```

Comment: I can recommend this site, if you want to find out how to create the code to register a custom post type or a custom taxonomy: http://generatewp.com/post-type/

Comment: I use <?php the_category(', '); ?> for this custom post category show in post only show (Posted In :Uncategorized) without link. but i add another category in this custom post

Comment: The function `the_category` is always using the default category taxonomy. Not some custom taxonomy you might have added. To get the values for your `portfolio-category` you have to use the function `the_terms` (or similar functions): http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms